# Is a MVC structure relevant in Python

Tags: java, python, model-view-controller

I come from Java, vanilla Java desktop software programming, recently switching to
Python

In Java, the basic routine of starting a MVC project, is making the model classes, setting up attributes, getter setters, then creating the views and coding up the logic with the controllers and constructors

Is all this relevant in Python? Creating a file for each class, heritage, method hierarchy, controllers, low coupling

I have a really hard time pre visualizing the structure and routine of a Python application , while utilizing the best from the language efficiency wise

Comment: you can use sqlalchemy for you models ... you can have a controller that is decoupled from a view but most python desktop GUI's dont really separate view and controller ... django and most web frameworks do typically separate the controller from the view

Comment: also here is an article about MVC in wxPython desktop GUI library http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController   (although really it boils down to a pubsub pattern, in which the controller subscribes to many emmited events)

Comment: It depends on whether you are writing a desktop app in Python. How that works tends to depend a fair bit on the GUI library you're using, since there is no widely used standard built-in like Swing.

Comment: "Creating a file for each class" - definitely don't do that bit. That's not an MVC thing; that's a Java thing.

Comment: MVC is a general design pattern of web services, it is not bind to any programming language!

Comment: @alfasin MVC is not 'a general design pattern for web services'.

Comment: @user2357112 how do I deduct which classes to keep in a same file? component structure?

Comment: @pvg the only (minor) correction is that it's a pattern for *any* UI not only webservices, but if you still disagree, please feel free to suggest a fix to wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller